# How to pass result from parent job to its continuation

Tags: hangfire

Since version 1.7.8 it is possible to pass results from parent job to continuation jobs in Hangfire. However there is no documentation or example supplied. While browsing code I realized that I need to use `ContinuationsSupport` attribute with `pushResults: true` argument. **But i have no idea how Hangfire saves the result and then how do I access the result.** I can't catch up with the code inside the attribute's class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appeared that it is enough to use the attribute with `pushResults`equal to true and then set the return type of the function to e. g. `string`. Then one can access this value produced by parent in continuation jobs by invoking `context.GetJobParameter<SomeType>("AntecedentResult")` where `context` is `PerformContext` (supplied by hangfire)

Answer (score 3):

I have written a small example, as I was struggling to understand where the context was coming from.

**Example**

```cs
public interface IReturnAValueProcess
{
   string Execute();
   
   // Can have multiple parameters besides the PerformContext
   void Continue(PerformContext context);
}
```

```cs
public class ReturnAValueProcess: IReturnAValueProcess
{
     public ReturnAValueProcess() {}
     
     [ContinuationsSupport(pushResults: true)]
     public string Execute()
     {
         Console.WriteLine("This job will return a string");

         return "Hello world";
     }

     public void Continue(PerformContext? context)
     {
         // This will write "Hello world" to the console, GetJobParameter type should be the same as whatever type is returned;
         Console.WriteLine(context.GetJobParameter<string>("AntecedentResult"));
     }
}
```

```cs
[Controller]
public class MyController : BaseController
{
   // Initialization, etc.

   [HttpGet]
   public void StartJob()
   {
      var process = new ReturnAValueProcess();
      var id = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => process.Execute());
      // We pass in null for the PerformContext argument, 
      // because Hangfire will substitute it with the correct context when executing the job
      var id2 = BackgroundJob.ContinueJobWith(id, () => process.Continue(null));
   }
}
```